# Using StringFormat with XAML Binding to inject folder into image path

Tags: c#, xaml, string-formatting

I'm trying to allow for multiple icon sizes depending on certain conditions. To do this, I have a bunch folders: 'Images\Icons\...\*.png' where the ... is the size (16, 32, 64, 128, 256, etc.) Each folder contains all the icons optimized for the given size.

My problem  I can't seem to specify a folder in the image source path... i.e.:

```
<Image x:Name  = "img" 
       Stretch = "None" 
       Source  = "{Binding StringFormat=Images\Icons\{0}\Multi.png, 
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                   Path=Parent.Parent.Tag}" />
```

For now, I'm just storing the folder name in the grandparent's tag (I will be binding to something else in the future, but right now I'm just trying to piece this bit together). When I try to build the above xaml, I get an error:

```
The text \Multi.png ... is not allowed after the closing } of a markup extension.
```

This leads me to beleave that it's seeing the {0} as a markup extension instead of it being a part of my string format. I've read about escaping with {} and using single quotes to specify the string format, but neither works:

```
Source  = "{Binding StringFormat={}Images\Icons\{0}\Multi.png, ...
```

The above returns the same error as when I don't escape at all..

```
Source  = "{Binding StringFormat='Images\Icons\{0}\Multi.png', ...

Source  = "{Binding StringFormat='{}Images\Icons\{0}\Multi.png', ...
```

The above two prevents the error from occurring, but results in the image source being null.

Does anyone know how to acheive this?

(Just to clarify, if the grandparent's tag is set to '16', then I want the image source bound to Images\Icons\16\Multi.png ... If the tag is set to '32' then I need to bind the source to Images\Icons\32\Multi.png. As a test, I set the grandparents tag to the full path, and excluded the stringformat. The relative binding to the grandparents tag succeeded and the image was shown. It only fails when I try to specify just the folder name with a stringformat to specify the rest of the path).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The StringFormatter attribute of Binding will only work if the target is of type String. Otherwise, it will simply be ignored.

You can fix this by adding a converter to your binding, which takes the format string and your tag, applies the formatting, and converts it to an ImageSource. In C#, your converter will look something like:

```
public sealed class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter == null || parameter.Equals(String.Empty)) parameter = "{0}";
        string path = String.Format((string) parameter, value);
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Once you've got your converter, you can add the following to your Resources in XAML:

```
<local:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" />
```

And modify your Source binding to:

```
<Image x:Name="img"
       Stretch="None"
       Source="{Binding Parent.Parent.Tag, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}, 
                        ConverterParameter='Images\\Icons\\{0}\\Multi.png', 
                        RelativeSource ={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" 
/>
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue.. if I use a string format of {}{0}, bind to the tag, and set the tag to the full path, it binds just fine. Isn't this functionally the same as using stringformat to inject the folder into the path? It still resolves to a string, which, as you've said, is automatically converted from a string to an ImageSurce, right? I think the issue is that it's seeing the {0} as the closing } of the markup extension... or am I just plain wrong (which is possible, as I'm relatively new to xaml).

Comment: @Chronicide I made some slight modifications to my code which fixed some of the bugs I had. I tested it to make sure it works.

Comment: Well, I've tried a bunch of tests, and I've confirmed your explanation. It turns out that it was completely ignoring the stringformat... which was why it would always work when the tag had the full path. Doing something similar when binding a text property worked with the string format. Thank you for your help, as I would never have worked that out. Also, thanks for you code. I was hoping to avoid a converter, but it works.